# Looking for a date widget operated by up and down arrow keys to increment date

Tags: javascript

I know some calendar widgets, but they do more than I need.

All I want is a text field with todays date and the ability to add or subtract a day by hitting the up or down arrow keys.

I know the keycodes 40 for down and 38 for up, and the onkeydown event, but don't know enough to put this together to have a functioning field. I thought to start like this:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo date('d.m.Y',mktime(date('H'))); ?>" onkeydown="keydownFunction()">
<script type="text/javascript">
function ArrowFun() {
    switch (window.event.keyCode) {
        case 38: ... +1 day
        break;
        case 40: ... -1 day
        break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Is there possibly a widget which does this already (I don't want a calendar popping up though)? I would go with a widget that has mouse operated arrow icons which lead to the same functionality as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `<input type="date">` is not sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) and [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

```
$(function() {
   var now = moment(); //Makes now a new moment, you could feed this the PHP date if needed as well...
   $('#dateBox').val(now.format('D.M.YYYY')); //Formats the date
   $('body').keydown(function(e) { //You can update the selector to #dateBox to refine it.
    switch(e.which) {
        case 38: // up
           $('#dateBox').val(now.add(1,'Day').format('D.M.YYYY'));
        break;

        case 40: // down
           $('#dateBox').val(now.subtract(1,'Day').format('D.M.YYYY'));
        break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
        });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rt8cd5uL/)

Comment: Super, thanks a buch, also for the fiddle.

How would I get the date format changed to 03.02.2016 for example? 
.format('d.m.YYYY') didn't do it.

Comment: @FrankSpade if this satisfied your question, can you mark it as your answer? Thanks!

Comment: This works great for me, but not only at the field with the id=datebox, but from other fields as well. See here https://jsfiddle.net/spade/rL19pbo8/
How can I prevent that?

Comment: Your event is on the `'body` so it is capturing any keypress, instead have the event on the `#dateBox` which will only capture keypress's while the focus is on `#dateBox`.

Comment: Life can be so easy. Thank you so much for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [library](http://momentjs.com), there is very useful methods to do that.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a powerful library, but I didn't see, how it can do what I want.